# SpEL using functions

Tags: spring, spring-el

I add to my xml next bean:

```
<bean id="PracticeFactory" class="WordsLearning.PracticeFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="#{teacher.getPracticeType()}"/>
    <constructor-arg value="#{teacher.getAboutType()}"/>
</bean>
```

And now, when I run application it is in cycle:

```
INFO: Refreshing    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@77a9aacd: startup date   [Tue Apr 09 20:35:47 EEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [EntityOperatorBean.xml]
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'stopTimer': replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut]; scope=prototype; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut]; scope=prototype; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@b4599c9: defining beans [entityOperator,word,timer,English-Russian,teacher,steady,terse,saver,Keyboard input,Vival trusted,PracticeFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#2,startTimer,stopTimer]; root of factory hierarchy
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1c038a03: startup date [Tue Apr 09 20:35:47 EEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [EntityOperatorBean.xml]
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'stopTimer': replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut]; scope=prototype; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut]; scope=prototype; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@24fbe4: defining beans [entityOperator,word,timer,English-Russian,teacher,steady,terse,saver,Keyboard input,Vival trusted,PracticeFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#2,startTimer,stopTimer]; root of factory hierarchy
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@5b3a6eda: startup date [Tue Apr 09 20:35:47 EEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [EntityOperatorBean.xml]
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'stopTimer': replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut]; scope=prototype; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut]; scope=prototype; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b9156ad: defining beans [entityOperator,word,timer,English-Russian,teacher,steady,terse,saver,Keyboard input,Vival trusted,PracticeFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#2,startTimer,stopTimer]; root of factory hierarchy
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@18c0364a: startup date [Tue Apr 09 20:35:47 EEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
апр 09, 2013 8:35:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [EntityOperatorBean.xml]
```

Without that bean it works correct.

Comment: this have the same result:  <bean id="PracticeFactory" class="WordsLearning.PracticeFactory">
        <property name="practice" value="#{teacher.practiceType}"/>
    </bean>
   teacher - another bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was beacuse the teacher bean has request to "beans.xml" and the priceFactory bean requests "beans.xml" and this is my cycle.

Comment: You may close this question by setting your answer as the solution.